# How to have different watermarks on title page, even pages and odd pages

Tags: titles, watermark, wallpaper

I would like to have a different background (wallpaper) on the title page, all even and all odd pages in a latex article document.

This is what I have so far:

```
% Set document background
\ifthenelse{\boolean{branding}}{
    \leftwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_page_even.pdf}}
    \rightwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_page_odd.pdf}}
}{}
```

I am using this snippet to set a different wallpaper on all the even and odd pages in my document.

I have created a new command to create the title page (to simplify usage for me). This is how the title page is created:

```
% Title page
\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{headers_title}
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{branding}}{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_title.pdf}}{}
        \begin{center}
            \vspace*{1.5cm}
            \Huge{\textbf{\title}}

            \vspace*{1.5cm}
            \LARGE{\subtitle}

            \Large{-- bla bla --}

            \vspace*{3.75cm}
            \Large{Peter Folta}
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
}
```

It places a special image on the title page. This works just fine, with the only problem that the title page now features two background images on top of each other: The title page image as well as the odd page image. This makes sense, as the title page is, in fact, an odd page. However, I'm looking for a solution to just have the title image on the title page.

Here is a minimal working example that illustrates my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage{watermark}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\leftwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_page_even.pdf}}
\rightwatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_page_odd.pdf}}

\newcommand{\maketitlepage}{
    \begin{titlepage}
        \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_title.pdf}
        \begin{center}
            Contents of title page ...
        \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
}

\begin{document}
    \maketitlepage

    Contents on an even page ...

    \newpage

    Contents on an odd page ...
\end{document}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) There are several packages thought for adding watermarks, and some provide commands for switching off the watermarks pagewise. So, the best would be, if you’d add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I've added an example in the main post, I hope that helps! Let me know if there's anything else I should provide.

Answer (score 5):

I've just solved the problem myself. Instead of just using the `\ThisCenterWallpaper` command I had to wrap it in another watermark command.

This solves the problem:

```
\thiswatermark{\ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{background_title.pdf}}
```