# How to put a watermark-wallpaper into a non-printing PDF layer in xetex?

Tags: xetex, watermark, ocg, wallpaper

Thanks to [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153222/430) I used

```
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{watermark}
\leftwatermark{
    Left
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{Wallpaper-L.pdf}
}
\rightwatermark{
    Right
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.0}{Wallpaper-R.pdf}
}
```

to have a full-sized pdf wallpaper on every page. I also [discovered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/278061/430) that [ocgx2](http://ctan.org/pkg/ocgx2) supports XeLaTeX to create PDF layers, so now I wanted to put the wallpaper into a non-printing layer by surrounding `\ThisCenterWallPaper` with a `\begin{ocg}[printocg=necer]{wallpaper}{wallpaper}{1}` (and respective `\end`) as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193071/430). Unfortunately, either `wallpaper` seems to "escape" the `ocg` environment, since the finished pdf has the layer but hiding it doesn't hide the wallpaper, nor does the print preview - the text, however, works.

I tried using other means to include the wallpaper, e.g. `background`'s `backgroundsetup` with `includegraphics`, but that always resulted in a non-fullsize wallpaper (possibly due to my using `geometry` to modify the margins?).

> In summary, I'm looking for means to include two pdf files as full-size, non-printing wallpapers (different ones for even and odd pages) in xetex...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example uses packages `ocgx2` (because of XeLaTeX), `tikz` and `atbegshi` in order to place non-printable watermarks into the background:

```
\documentclass[twoside,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{mwe}

\AtBeginShipout{%
  \AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
    \begin{ocg}[printocg=never,showingui=never]{watermark}{watermark}{on}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
      \node [opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) {%
        \ifodd\thepage%
          \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}%
        \else%                                                           
          \includegraphics[angle=90,width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}%
        \fi%
      };
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{ocg}%
  }%
}

\usepackage{ocgx2}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-29]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just seen that `ocgx` supports XeLaTeX as well.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! `ocgx` needs `showingui` replaced by `listintoolbar` though (untested), at least that's what [ocgx2's README](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/ocgx2/README) suggests at a quick glance. That also suggests using `\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}` (instead of  the additional `\usepackage{tikz}`)

Comment: `[tikz]` option is not necessary here. Actually, it replaces the `\usetikzlibrary{ocgx}` line, which, according to the`ocgx` manual, enables some additional TikZ styles that can be used to associate TikZ `scopes` with OCGs, and to turn TikZ nodes into clickable buttons for changing OCG visibility. Read the `ocgx` manual for further details. In general, I recommend using `ocgx2` since it extends the `ocgx` functionality and fixes some bugs inherited from the `ocg-p` package which `ocgx` loads under the hood.

Comment: There is probably no reason to not use `ocgx2` indeed... Why did you choose `opacity=0.3` by the way?

Comment: Minor caveat: This will draw _over_ `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`

Comment: As for opacity, I was thinking the background image would look more watermarkish that way. As for `showframe`, I would experiment with the loading order of the packages. As `geometry` also modifies the shipout routine via `atbegshi`, I would try loading `geometry` just before the document begins.

Comment: Good point, this also fixed the margins being scaled wrong, probably due to my putting all this into a custom class based on `scrbook`...